# How to export the following table?

Tags: export, data

Consider a table

```
   table1= {{"Quantity", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(exp0\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(exp1\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(exp2\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(exp3\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(exp3\\\ \((larger)\)\)]\)", 
      "<E\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(>\), \(exp0\)]\) [GeV]", 
      "<E\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(>\), \(exp1\)]\) [GeV]", 
      "<E\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(>\), \(exp2\)]\) [GeV]", 
      "<E\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(>\), \(exp3\)]\) [GeV]"}, {"Hons",
      11.3, 12.4, 
      1.2, 0., 
     18.3,88.9, 
     12.3, 2.6, 3.4}}
```

Could you please tell me how to export this table in the external file correctly? Exporting in CSV format does not work properly.

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: @N.J.Evans I want the imported file to look exactly like the input from the question looks after inserting in the Mathematica notebook.

Comment: What is the purpose of exporting? Do you want to be able to export this table so you can import it in another notebook for future calculations? Then I'd use `Save["table.wl",table1]`. Or you want a table with all of the greeks correct that is nice for reading? `Export["table.pdf",TableForm[Transpose@table1]]` You're going to have clarify a little, I think.

Comment: @N.J.Evans : thank you! The first option was the one I was looking for.